# Python Selenium: I can't click on a button - no id, value, name corresponding to button tag

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

I'm using Selenium to click the "Become A Member" button from this link: https://www2.hm.com/en_us/register.

Here is the HTML of the button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjeu3.png

I have exhausted all other answers on this site: I have tried to find this element using XPath, CSS Selector, waited for element to be clickable, visible, etc. all but to no avail.

Here is my current code that accepts all the cookies (since I thought that was the problem) and then tries to click on the "Become a Member" button

```
try:
    # Accepts cookies
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()

    # Clicks the register button
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[data-testid='submitButton']"))).click()

except:
    print("Driver waited too long!")
    driver.quit()
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code instead of pictures. Respondents may need to debug your samples.

Comment: Selenium supports partial matching. Have you searched for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to click on `Become A Member` button you are using `input[data-testid='submitButton']` which is almost correct but it's not input tag, it's a button.

See the HTML here :

```
<button class="CTA-module--action__3hGPH CTA-module--medium__dV8ar CTA-module--primary__3hPd- CTA-module--fullWidth__1GZ-5 RegisterForm--submit__2Enwx" data-testid="submitButton" type="submit"><span>BECOME A MEMBER</span></button>
```

so changing `input[data-testid='submitButton']` to `button[data-testid='submitButton']` did the trick and it worked.

**Sample code : -**

```
try:
    # Accepts cookies
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()

    # Clicks the register button
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='submitButton']"))).click()

except:
    print("Driver waited too long!")
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I have tried two similar approaches:
(1)  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='BECOME A MEMBER']").click()`

(2)  `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'submitButton')]"))).click()` Perhaps you can tell me why these two didn't work for me?

Comment: 2nd xpath that you have tried is not present in DOM, 1st is present but not locating to the button we actaully want, try this `//span[text()='BECOME A MEMBER']/..`